# call a function every X minute

Tags: java, android

I have a background service running and inside this I wanted to call a function every X minute. What is the simplest solution to do this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ScheduledExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)